# Using Boost library in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

not particularly good with this kind of stuff I have managed to install the Boost C++ library and this basic program works with the g++ compiler and linking to the right .dylib files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main()
{
filesystem::path path1("/Users/username/Documents/testfile.txt"); 
filesystem::remove(path1); 
std::cout << "It worked" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Now I would like to do the same, just using Xcode to build and run the program, but it doesn't work. I have done everything in this tutorial:

http://buddypanda.com/?p=10

i.e. include header and library search paths, as well as linked the .dylib files of filesystem and system under the 'Build Phases' tab.

The Build succeeds but then the program crashed with an error of EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I can maybe provide more specifics on what goes wrong if you tell me where to look.

Thanks!

EDIT1: I am using g++-4.9 and Boost-1.58 and Xcode 6.4

Comment: My best guess is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Possibly because of conflicting version of libraries during build as opposed to runtime. Or conflicting compiler options

Comment: What is UB? An how could libraries be conflicting if I have only installed this one?

Comment: I linked to the wikipedia page for a reason. Stackoverflow is a Q&A site and has a search box :) It's not constructive to keep convincing yourself your problem cannot exist. Your problem exists. You need to fix it...

Comment: What would I need to look into to fix it?

Comment: The versions and compiler options of the libraries vs. the application you're linking against it.

Comment: And I didn't see the link as I was on my phone...Not a reason to become insulting, UB stands for management consultancy in german where I come from, sorry!

Comment: Well. I don't see where I was insulting. I just noticed the pattern of "An how could libraries be conflicting if I have only installed this one?" - this is typical "I don't want the problem to exist" rhetorics. Step 1: to solving problems: accept them. Step 2: Look at them. It's just me being hellpful to tell it as I detect it :0

Comment: I have added the versions of everything involved, don't know if I use any compiler options.